# Replace form placeholder text using javascript - form not on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, placeholder

I’m trying to replace a form placeholder text using javascript.
Sample page: https://www.globalcallforwarding.com/lps/sign-up-try-free/

We want to replace “Enter valid phone number” with an actual number. The issue is, the form is being pulled in from another server, which is complex, and we can’t change the source files on that server. I have been successful swapping out the placeholder on a sample form (bottom of page), but the javascript has no effect on the top form. Any ideas on how we can target that field?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
         $('form').find("input[type=tel], tel").each(function(ev)
         {
            if(!$(this).val()) {  
             $("#dstnumber").attr("placeholder", "(555) 555-5555").val("").focus().blur();
         }
         });
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how are you getting the 'top' form? is it already there when the javascript is executed?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be loaded dynamically, which is why it cant be found in $(document).ready.

You should be able to target the top form using this function.

https://gist.github.com/chrisjhoughton/7890303

```
var waitForEl = function(selector, callback) {
  if (jQuery(selector).length) {
    callback();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      waitForEl(selector, callback);
    }, 100);
  }
};

var selector = jQuery('#dstnumber'); 

waitForEl(selector, function() { 
  // Will run when the element exists 
  jQuery(selector).attr("placeholder", "(555) 555-55551111").val("").focus().blur();
});
```

Comment: I tried adding  document.querySelector('input[type=tel]').placeholder = "(555) 555-5555";  in the // work the magic section...nothing happens. I also tried this document.getElementById("dstnumber").placeholder = "(555) 555-5555";

Comment: Try it like this. :) 

var selector = jQuery('#dstnumber');

waitForEl(selector, function() {
 // Will run when the element exists
  console.log(selector);
});

Comment: I appreciate your help, but still not doing anything. Where would I put the custom info 555-5555? I input your code here https://www.globalcallforwarding.com/lps/sign-up-try-free/